# Android database location on my Mac

Tags: android, database, location

I would like to know how I can access the copy of my sqlite database on my device.

I have an android app, and as far as I know, when you run the app it makes a copy from your database to work with (makes a file database.sql).

Now is my question how can I access the database.sql file on my mac? I want to remove it.

I have found that it's located under /data/data/APP_NAME/database/sql. But I can't seem to find the map data/data. Where is the root map for this? Where should I look?

I'm working on a macbook.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have root access on your phone you can't explore that path. 
Try it with the emulator, and then use de ADB shell to access de database file.

Comment: How do I remove it by using the ADB shell?

Comment: Just go inside the shell, go to the path, and then remove the file:
$ adb shell
$ cd /data/data/APP_NAME/databases/
$ rm my_database.sql

Comment: When I remove that file (which works) and run my app again, the old data is still in there. How is this possible? Or do I have to clear it by doing something else? The thing is that I have a new database and want the new data in my app. I'm not used to work with android. By an iPhone app you just have to remove the copied database. How is this done with android?

Comment: Maybe if you post the code we can help. Check from where your app copies the new database (maybe from the assets folder on your project), and make sure it's the newest file.

Comment: Well, I'm using titanium appcelerator. It does it automatically when you open the database.